# Prove that $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n}$ is not an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an elementary proof that $∑_{k=1}^n 1/k$ is never an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/is-there-an-elementary-proof-that-k-1n-1-k-is-never-an-integer)

Hello,

> Prove that $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n}$ is not an integer.

I tried to prove by induction on $n$, but I was stuck :(

Assume $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n} = \frac{a}{b}$ for some integers $a, b$ and $a \neq b \text{and} b \neq 0$
Then $ 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n + 1} = \frac{a}{b} + \frac{1}{n + 1}$

Then how can I prove that this expression is not integer? A hint would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: Look at the power of 2 divisible by numerator and denominator.

Comment: Your induction hypothesis is not strong enough, because simply assuming that $k$ is not an integer does not guarantee that $k+\frac{1}{n+1}$ is not an integer. So if you want to proceed by induction, you need to prove more than simply that $H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots + \frac{1}{n}$ is not an integer, you need to prove something about its expression as a rational written in lowest terms.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Thanks, that was exactly the problem that I encountered, since I actually found counter examples.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/is-there-an-elementary-proof-that-k-1n-1-k-is-never-an-integer and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5219/how-do-i-prove-this-sum-is-not-an-integer

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Would saying that for $n=2$ the series is not an integer suffice? Proof by example?

Comment: @Jacob: No.  Although not explicitly stated in the question, the subsequent remarks on trying to prove it make it clear that Chan wants to show that it is never an integer when $n\geq 2$, not just there there exists an $n$ such that it is not an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: look at the largest power of 2 less than $n$. Can it get canceled out from the denominator?

Comment: I think it can be? Do you mean n!?

Comment: See the discussion on the question linked at the top: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2746/264

Answer (score 11):

**HINT**: There is always a prime between $\frac{n}{2}$ and $n$, $\forall n \geq 4$

Comment: That's overkill.