# Show that $a_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}$ would not contain a natural number for all n

Tags: number-theory

Show that the series: $a_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}$ would not contain natural number for all n

Can I prove that  using "simple tools"?

Comment: Try Induction to prove it.

Comment: What would  be the induction step?

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate of another MSE question, unfortunately I can't remember the link right now

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question, e.g. see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24113/prove-that-1-frac12-frac13-frac1n-is-not-an-integer

Comment: @Nehorai The sums differ by $\frac{1}{1}$, and $x$ is an integer if and only if $x+1$ is one. The interesting part of the problem is exactly the same in both questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can prove this using simple tools. For example you can prove by induction that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $S_n$ is a ratio of an odd number and an even number, so it's not an integer.