# elementary proof for $1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + … + \frac{1}{2n+1}$ is not an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that for any $n\ge 1$ 
$$
1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + … + \frac{1}{2n+1}
$$ 
is not an integer.

A hint would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Payam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n}$ is not an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24113/prove-that-1-frac12-frac13-frac1n-is-not-an-integer)

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa The given link deals with a different sum. Please explain why you think this is a duplicate.

Comment: It is slightly hidden, but the linked question is all the current OP needs, since $$1+\frac13+\ldots+\frac1{2n+1}=1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots+\frac1{2n+1}-\frac12\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots+\frac1{n}\right)$$

Comment: @– DonAntonio: It is possible to explain how the right side of above equation is not integer? If A and B is not integer there is no reason to A-1/2 B is not integer.

Comment: A simple proof, similar in spirit to the corresponding proof of $1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\cdots$, is to observe that among the denominators there is a **unique** one divisible by a hgher power of three than the others. In other words, instead of using the non-archimedean 2-adic triangle inequality we use the 3-adic triangle inequality.