# Sum of reciprocal odd numbers is not an integer

Tags: number-theory

Is there an elementary proof that sum $1/3+1/5+1/7+...+1/(2n+1)$ is not an integer for every n?

Comment: hint: chebyshev's theorem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an elementary proof that $\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \frac1k$ is never an integer?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/is-there-an-elementary-proof-that-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1k-is-never-an-int)

Answer (score 1):

We have shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141224/finite-sum-of-reciprocal-odd-integers) that
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{2k-1}&=\frac12(2H_{2n}-H_n),
\end{align*}$$
where $H_n$ is the harmonic number. Now $H_n$ for $n>1$ is never an integer, see [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/is-there-an-elementary-proof-that-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1k-is-never-an-int), where several elementary proofs have been given. This implies that no difference $H_{n+k}-H_n$
is an integer, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5219/how-do-i-prove-this-sum-is-not-an-integer).
The same reasoning should work to see that also $H_{2n}-H_n/2$ is never an integer.

Comment: But $2H_{2n}-H_n$ could be, no ?

Comment: No, but good point. I have to fill the gap..