# Prove difference of harmonic numbers is not an integer using Bertrand's Postulate

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ and $m$ be positive integers. Show that $\sum_{i=n}^{n+m}\frac{1}{i}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{n+m}$ is not an integer using Bertrand's postulate.

There are a few posts asking a similar question (e.g. [How do I prove this sum is not an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5219/how-do-i-prove-this-sum-is-not-an-integer)) but none of them use Bertrand's postulate.

Firstly, I'm not sure if you can use it. Say that $n=8$ and $m=2$, then the sum is,
$$\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}$$
and there are no primes in the denominator as I would like to use.

Comment: Show $m\le n-1$ implies the sum is strictly less than $1$.

Comment: You meant to write $\sum_{i = n}^{n + m} \frac{1}{i} = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n + 1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n + m}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is thanks to Gerry Myerson's insight.

There are 2 possibilities, (1) $n\le m$. Bertrand's postulate applies, and use the reasoning from [Is there an elementary proof that $\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \frac1k$ is never an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/is-there-an-elementary-proof-that-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1k-is-never-an-int)

Possibility (2), $n>m$. We have, the sum,
$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{n+m}\le\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n-1}< \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n}{n}=1$$
hence it is not an integer.