# Let $n>1$, then prove that $1+ 1/2+1/3+\cdots+1/n$ is not an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an elementary proof that $\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \frac1k$ is never an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/is-there-an-elementary-proof-that-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1k-is-never-an-int)

Let $n>1$, then prove that $\;1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\cdots +\dfrac{1}{n}\;$ is not an integer.

Thanks

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2746/9464