# Sum $\sum \frac{1}{n}\not \in N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

If $S_n$ denote sum of $n$ terms of H.P. $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4}$ ..... , Then prove **using summation of series** that $S_n\not\in N$ $\forall \ n \in N$;

Comment: check out [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/is-there-an-elementary-proof-that-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1k-is-never-an-int)

Comment: What do you mean by your emphasis on 'using summation of series?'

Answer (score 2):

For $\,n\ge 2\,$:

$$S_n:=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n!+\frac{n!}{2}+\frac{n!}{3}+\ldots+\frac{n!}{n}}{n!}$$

If we now choose $\,k\in\Bbb N \;\;s.t.\;\;2^k\mid n!\;,\;\;2^{k+1}\nmid n!\,$ , then *all* the summands in the last expression's numerator are even *except* one, namely

$$\frac{n!}{2^k}$$

and thus that expression's numerator is odd, whereas the denominator isn't...

Comment: are u sure this would be accepted as a answer to the question: " using summation of series"?

Comment: No, I am not since I don't know what "using summation of series" can possibly mean.

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't know what I'm missing-If n=7, 7!/4 = 1260, which is even...

Comment: but in this case, k =2 and k+1 =3, so that 4| 7! and 8|7! also. So that k does not satisfy the condition that $2^k | n! $ and $ 2^{k+1}\nmid n!$