# Can the difference of two Harmonic numbers be an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, harmonic-numbers

It is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/is-there-an-elementary-proof-that-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1k-is-never-an-int) that the Harmonic numbers

$$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$$

are never integers for $n>1$.

Can the difference of two Harmonic numbers

$$H_n-H_m=\sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{1}{k}$$

be an integer if $n>m>1$?

Comment: If I am not wrong it can not be integer, because you can take the highest power of $2$ that the denominators contain and notice that there is only one fraction which denominator contains that power of $2$.

Comment: You should also be able to prove it by induction on the number of terms in the sum.