# Prove that the difference between Harmonic numbers not natural number

Tags: harmonic-numbers

The harmonic number $H_n$ is defined as $$H_n = \frac11 + \frac12 + \cdots + \frac1n$$
I need to show that $H_n - H_k$ can't be a Natural number, when $n>k$. I understand that the sum is greater than $\ln\big(\frac{n}{k}\big)$ but I don't know how it helps.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You're right in that the estimate doesn't help at all.  This is a number theory question, no calculus involved.

Comment: Same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086641/can-the-difference-of-two-harmonic-numbers-be-an-integer?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of hints.  We want to evaluate $$\sum_{j=k+1}^n\frac1j$$
Let $s$ be the greatest integer such that $2^s$ divides one of the numbers $k+1,k+2,\dots,n$.

First, show that $2^s$ divides exactly one of these numbers.

Then, suppose $$\sum_{j=k+1}^n\frac1j=N\tag1$$ for some integer $N$.

Multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $2^{s-1}$ and observe that exactly one of the terms has an even denominator.  Deduce a contradiction.  (Hint: what can you say about the sum of two fractions with odd denominators?