# HELP! Prove that the number $\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$ is not an integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that the number $$\sum_{k=2}^{n}{1\over k}$$ is not an integer.

Comment: This is a duplicate, I think.

Comment: What do you mean "duplicate"?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/is-there-an-elementary-proof-that-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1k-is-never-an-int

Comment: @dezdichado thank you very much!

Comment: In this site, a question that has been asked before is not recommended to be asked again, unless it provides new insight. If a problem asked before is asked again, it is called a 'duplicate'. Most 'duplicates' are 'closed' quickly. When it is 'closed' you can no longer post new answers, and is likely to be downvoted.

Comment: How do I know if it has been asked before ? (I'm new here)

Comment: I recommend you use the search function. It's not always helpful, though. It might help for you to browse some other questions that have been asked before in your free time.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i}$ is an integer, $n>1$. By Bertrand's postulate, there exists a prime $\frac{n}{2}<p<n$. If we make the common denominator of the fraction, we get $$\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i} = \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i=1}^n (2\times 3 \times ... \times (i-1) \times (i+1) \times ... \times n)$$.

Note that $p$ divides the denominator of the above fraction, but in the numerator all terms in the sum except the term $(1\times 2 \times ... \times (p-1) \times (p+1) \times ... \times n)$,and because we have assumed that $\frac{n}{2}<p<n$, this term does not divide $p$ because it can't contain a multiple of $p$. Hence it follows that $p$ does not divide the numerator of the fraction. Hence it follows that the fraction cannot be made an integer for any $n$.

Comment: Does the "$\times$" symbol is the same as"$\cdot$" ?

Comment: Yes, both mean multiplication, but the difference is that $\cdot$ often is used for multiplication in groups and rings, while $\times$ is used for multiplying real numbers . By the way, hope you know about Bertrand's postulate. Erdos proved it at the age of nineteen.

Comment: Of course. But I thought "$\times$" was used for multiplication in groups and rings and "$\cdot$" for real numbers. Maybe it's oposite in my country...

Comment: Your country Greece? Cyprus? Macedonia? All said and done, maybe it is the opposite, but the textbook I use is written by a man from the United Kingdom, while I myself have seen it in use in India.

Comment: I'm from Greece my friend

Comment: But I think $x\cdot x\cdot\ldots\cdot x\neq x\times x\times\ldots\times x$, lol!

Comment: Well, I'm from India, but our notation is British borrowed because we were once their colony. So we use $\times$ whenever there is some relation between $a$ and $b$ i.e. $a \times b = b \times a$ or $a \times b = -b \times a$, while the group product, which has no property other than associativity, is denoted by $\cdot$. I saw it written in I.N.Herstein, a British author. Besides, even $+$ is used, but only for strictly commutative operations. It must be different in Greece though. I have seen variations in papers published in Russia and Slovakia in this regard.