# Prove that: $1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+...+\frac{1}{2n+1}$ is not an Integer for any integer $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, prime-numbers, induction

I have already solved this problem by writing the above sum as $$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Let z1= the first series and z2 be the second(inside brackets). 
We know that z1,z2 are not integers.

Therefore if the sum is an integer, $2\left\{z_1\right\}=\left\{z_2\right\}$  ({} denotes the fractional part)

This implies there is no new prime in the denominator of z1 which is not already present in z2.

$\Rightarrow $ There is no p such that $n\le p\le 2n+1$

Since this clearly contradicts Bertrand's postulate, the given sum is not an integer.

I wanted to know if there is anyway to solve it by induction.

Thanks ☺

Comment: I doubt induction can prove a sequence is of *non*-integers, unless the fractional parts take a simple form.

Comment: I would not use induction at all. Instead I would do a $3$-adic argument. In the sum there is a *unique* denominator divisible by a higher power of $3$ than any other term. This implies that powers of $3$ cannot cancel in the sum. IIRC this is an exercise in Desmond & Murty.

Comment: Ok...I think I understand. Thanks.

Comment: The same idea as [in the linked thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2746/11619), only with the prime $3$ instead of $2$.