# Is $H_m - H_n$ a surjection onto $\mathbb{Q}^+$?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, rational-numbers, harmonic-numbers

I was wondering whether, for each rational $q$, we may always write

$$q = \sum_{k=a}^b \frac 1k$$

For some positive integers $a \leq b$. I get the feeling that this is *not* true (although an immediate consequence of $\mathbb{R}^+$ being Archimedean is that the set of such $q$ is dense). I'm sure there is some slick proof using Bertrand's postulate (as is typical with these problems) but I'm not seeing it. This post is partly a reference request, as I'm sure this has been touched on before in some article, and would like to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get $H_m-H_n=2$, or any integer $\ge2$.

In a sum $1/(n+1)+\cdots+1/m$ exactly one of the terms has minimal
$2$-adic valuation. This can only be zero if one has only one term.
Therefore there's a power of $2$ in the denominator, which cannot
be $2^0$ save in the cases $H_{n+1}-H_n=1/(n+1)$ where $n+1$ is odd.

Answer (score 4):

The proof given at [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Harmonic_Number_is_not_Integer) and at [Is there an elementary proof that $\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \frac1k$ is never an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/) for the fact that no harmonic number $H_n$ for $n\gt1$ is an integer also works for this case.

There is a unique denominator in $[a,b]$ that is divisible by the highest power of $2$. If $q$ is an integer, multiply through by one less factor of $2$ to turn all terms except one into integers (which is impossible). The only case to which this doesn’t apply is when the sum only runs over a single odd integer; and in this case the sum is also not an integer, except for $H_1=1$.