# If $ 1+ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+.....+\frac{1}{100}=\frac{A}{B}$ where $A$ and $B$ are coprime positive integers, then $5\nmid A$ and $5\nmid B$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, harmonic-numbers

> Let the sum $$1+ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+.....+\frac{1}{100}=\frac{A}{B}$$ where $A,B\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\gcd(A,B)=1$.  Show that neither $A $ nor $B $ is divisible by $5$.

My attempt: $$\begin{align}1+ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{100}&=(1+\frac{1}{100})+(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{99})+\cdots +(\frac{1}{50}+\frac{1}{51})\\&=101(\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{2\times99}+\frac{1}{3\times 98}+\ldots+\frac{1}{51 \times 50})\,.\end{align}$$ denominator is $100!$ and numerator is multiple of $101$. Now how to prove the statement? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clearly the denominator is not $100!$ because this is divisible by $5$.

Comment: This sum equals $$ \frac{14466636279520351160221518043104131447711}{2788815009188499086581352357412492142272}$$ according to Mathematica.

Comment: Maybe the following is interesting, too: [The partial sum of the harmonic series, $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1 i $ is never an ineger](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/is-there-an-elementary-proof-that-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1k-is-never-an-int). It has always an even denominator and an odd numerator, if they are relatively prime

Answer (score 2):

Let $S:=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{100}\,\dfrac1{k}$, and write $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ for each positive integer $n$.  Note that $B$ is not divisible by $5$ because
$$\begin{align}S&=\sum_{\substack{k\in[100]\\ 5\nmid k}}\,\dfrac1k +\frac15\,\sum_{\substack{k\in[20]\\5\nmid k}}\frac1k+\frac1{25}\,\sum_{k=1}^4\,\frac1k\tag{1}
\\&=\sum_{\substack{k\in[100]\\ 5\nmid k}}\,\dfrac1k +\frac15\,\sum_{t=0}^{3}\,\sum_{r=1}^4\frac1{5t+r}+\frac{1}{25}\cdot\frac{25}{12}\tag{2}
\\&=\sum_{\substack{k\in[100]\\ 5\nmid k}}\,\dfrac1k +\frac15\,\sum_{t=0}^{3}\,\left(\frac{10t+5}{(5t+1)(5t+4)}+\frac{10t+5}{(5t+2)(5t+3)}\right)+\frac{1}{12}\tag{3}
\\&=\sum_{t=0}^{19}\,\sum_{r=1}^4\,\frac{1}{5t+r} +\sum_{t=0}^{3}\,(2t+1)\left(\frac{1}{(5t+1)(5t+4)}+\frac{1}{(5t+2)(5t+3)}\right)+\frac{1}{12}\tag{4}\,.\end{align}$$
Now, $A$ is not divisible by $5$ because, from the equation above,
$$\begin{align}S&\equiv \sum_{t=0}^{19}\,\sum_{r=1}^4\,\frac{1}{5t+r}+\sum_{t=0}^3\,(2t+1)\left(\frac{1}{1\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}\right)+\frac{1}{12}\pmod{5}\tag{5}
\\&\equiv \sum_{t=0}^{19}\,\sum_{r=1}^4\,\frac{1}{r}+\left(\frac{1-5}{1\cdot 4}+\frac{1+5}{2\cdot 3}\right)\,\sum_{t=0}^3\,(2t+1)+\frac{1-25}{12}\pmod{5}\tag{6}
\\&\equiv \sum_{t=0}^{19}\,\frac{25}{12}+\big((-1)+1\big)(1+3+5+7)-2\pmod{5}\tag{7}
\\&\equiv 0+0\cdot 16-2 =-2\not\equiv 0\pmod{5}\tag{8}\,.\end{align}$$

---

**Exercise for the Reader.**  Let $\dfrac{A}{B}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{20}\,\dfrac{1}{k}$, where $A$ and $B$ are relatively prime positive integers.  Prove that $5$ divides $A$ but $25$ does not divide $A$.  Prove also that $5$ does not divide $B$.

Comment: How do you get from the second line to the third line above?

Comment: @RobertShore I am putting tags on the first equation, because I am not sure  which line to which line.  Can you please refer to the numbered lines?

Comment: I don't see how you get from $(2)$ to $(3)$.  Thanks.  Never mind.  I see it now.

Comment: @RobertShore  Write $$\frac{1}{5t+1}+\frac{1}{5t+2}+\frac{1}{5t+3}+\frac{1}{5t+4}$$ as $$\left(\frac{1}{5t+1}+\frac{1}{5t+4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{5t+2}+\frac{1}{5t+3}\right)\,.$$