# A proof of the theorem $1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n} = \frac{k}{m}$ with $k$ odd and $m$ even

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, summation, parity

I tried to prove the following theorem :

> If $n>1$ then $\displaystyle1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n} = \frac{k}{m}$ where $k$ is odd and $m$ is even.

and I'd like to know if there is any flaw in my argument.

---

**Proof** :

For $n = 2$ and $n=3%$ we verify the theorem directly.

When $n \geq 4$ we can argue as follows :

First of all we sum up all the fractions obtaining

$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}= \frac{n!+1\cdot3\cdots n+\dots+(n-1)!}{n!} \:\:\:\:\:\:\:(1)$$

Now I define the multi-parity function $P$ as a function which counts the number of twos in the factorization of an integer, for example $44 = 2^2 \cdot 11$ so $P(44) = 2$.

Every product $c$ in the numerator of $(1)$ has $P(c) \geq P(n!) - \max[P(x)]$ where $1\leq x \leq n$ . This is true because every product in the numerator has just one factor less than $n!$ , for example we know that $P(1\cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot n)=P(n!)-1$.

Moreover we know that $P(c) = P(n!) - \max[P(x)]$ in only one case that is when $c$ hasn't the greatest power of two less than $n$ in the product.

So using $g = \max[P(x)]$, which is also always equal or greater than $1$,  and $q = P(n!) - g$ we can gather $2^q$ in the numerator and $2^{q+g}$ in the denominator :
$$\frac{n!+1\cdot3 \cdots n+\dots+(n-1)!}{n!} = \frac{2^q(a_1+\dots+a_n)}{2^{q+g}m}  = \frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{2^{g}m}$$

but the denominator is even because $g \geq 1$ and the numerator is odd since  all the $a_i$ are even except for one.

---

Is my argument sound ?

Anyway I found the problem in the great book *Introduction to algorithms* by Udi Manber and I found there are [lots of threads](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/is-there-an-elementary-proof-that-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1k-is-never-an-int) about this problem on MSE and my proof is similar to the elementary proof of the statement without Bertrand Postulate but I enjoyed proving it by myself :-)

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Thanks @saulspatz for your feedback!

Comment: @Tortar What is $k$ here?

Comment: @Algebrology what do you mean by what is $k$? Do you refer to the fact that maybe stating "at lowest terms" is better?

Comment: btw, you should look up $v_{p}$ cos it seems like you might have accidentally discovered it..

Comment: @Aditya_math yes I realized it when I read the threads on this topic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument seems sounds, but it's pretty involved. Here's a simpler proof in case you're interested.

Suppose the statement is true for $2,3,\ldots,n - 1$.

Consider:

$$\frac a c = 1 + \frac 1 3 + \cdots + \frac 1 p$$ where $p$ is the largest odd number less than $n$
and

$$\frac b d = \frac 1 2 + \cdots + \frac 1 q$$ where $q$ is the largest even number less than $n$.

Then we have that

$$\frac b d = \frac 1 2 + \cdots + \frac 1 q = \frac 1 2 \left(1 + \frac 1 2 +\frac 1 3+ \cdots + {1\over{q/2}}\right)$$

so $b$ is odd and $d$ is even.

When $q = 2$, $b = 1$, and $d = 2$.

By induction hypothesis we know that for $q > 2$, we have
$$1 + \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 + \cdots + {1\over{q/2}}$$
so we see that $d$ is even and $b$ is odd.

Now we know $c$ must be odd because $1,3,5,\ldots,p$ are all odd.

Lastly,

\begin{align}
    1 + \frac1 2 + \frac 1 3 + \cdots + \frac 1 n &= \frac a c + \frac b d\\
    &={ad + bc \over cd}
\end{align}
so we see that the numerator is odd and the denominator is even.

Comment: I think you mean $p$ ($q$) is the largest odd (even) number less than or equal to $n$.

Comment: yes, clearly simpler than mine :-)